# Get AWS Lambda url from cdk and insert it into a frontend application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have an aws cdk stack i am writing in typescript. It consists of a react app stored in an s3 bucket (via s3 bucket deployment). I also have an api gateway running a websocket api. I now need to join the two together, by telling the react app the url of the api gateway, ideally via the deploy step.

I have tried writing the token to a file before deploying, but the string is still tokenised, so i end up with `wss://${Token[TOKEN.243]}...`, so the write is too early. I have tried writing the file via `cdk deploy -O` but at that point its too late to ship it with the deploy.

How can I inform my react application of the web api url?

Comment: Why don't you have a fixed Route 53 entry so your react app doesn't need to change every time the backend changes? Then you can just have your route 53 entry be updated to point to the output of the api gateway endpoint

Comment: I'm still pretty new to the AWS landscape - wasn't aware of this. I'll give it a read, by the sounds of it its what we need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When I do this pattern, I will use CloudFront to proxy /api/* to my API Gateway and everything else to the S3 bucket website url.  Then the react code just has to make requests on /api

Comment: I should have added the detail that it's a websocket api. I gave this a go and i seem to have issues with the websocket messages delayed and being repeated.

Answer (score -1):

You can divide your Stack in 2 parts.

1. Api Stack
2. ReactApp stack

Deploy `Api Stack` first with `-O` options to write api url into some json file in directory getting deployed to s3.

Now you have json having api url in json file and you can deploy `ReactApp Stack` now.

Note: In your react app you can should read  the url from the file that will be generated by `cdk deploy -O <filename>.json`.